# chrome.desktopCapture.chooseDesktopMedia callback always returning undefined

Tags: google-chrome-extension

Does anybody know why my code below always returns *undefined* variable in the callback. From the api documentation it says that it is stable in chrome 34, I have already updated my chrome into chrome 34 but still I get undefined value.

```
chrome.desktopCapture.chooseDesktopMedia(
  ["screen", "window"],
  function (streamId) {
      console.log(streamId); //always returns undefined.
  });
```

By the way I am using Ubuntu 32-bit with chrome version 34.0.1847.132

Comment: Two observations: I have seen reports that it currently doesn't work on Linux in general, and there's this consideration: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18539415/934239 See if it helps.

Comment: I just updated to Chrome 37 and have the same issue on Windows 8.1. Here is the link to the documentation: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/desktopCapture

Answer (score 0):

Chrome always fires the callback, even when it has an exception. You have to check for [`chrome.runtime.lastError`](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/runtime#property-lastError):

```
chrome.desktopCapture.chooseDesktopMedia(
  ["screen", "window"],
  streamId => {
      if(chrome.runtime.lastError)
          console.error(chrome.runtime.lastError);
      else
          console.log(streamId);
  });
```

Alternatively you can use an asynchronous/Promise wrapper library like [`chrome-extension-async`](https://github.com/KeithHenry/chromeExtensionAsync) so that you can catch the `await` exception:

```
try {
    streamId = await chrome.desktopCapture.chooseDesktopMedia(["screen", "window"]);
    console.log(streamId);
}
catch(err) { 
    console.error(err);
}
```